# Differentiate between optional functional parameters in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

Is it possible to differentiate between optional parameters (of different types) in typescript? I have a function that takes one of two parameters and constructs an object with certain values filled, depending on the parameter provided:

```
type Video {
  name: string; 
  id: number;
  // other stuff
}

type VideoForm {
  name: string; 
  file?: File; // Only exists if created with a file
  id?: number; // Only exists if created with a Video
}

function createVideo(
  uploadedVideo?: Video,
  file?: File
) {
  // if we get uploadedVideo, create VideoForm with video
  // if we get the file, create VideoForm with file
}
```

When I call `createVideo(file)`, typescript thinks that I am attempting to pass `file` as a `Video`. My workaround was to try `createVideo(undefined, file)`, but I'm hoping there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this quote from the typescript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters),

> In JavaScript, every parameter is optional, and users may leave them
> off as they see fit. When they do, their value is undefined. We can
> get this functionality in TypeScript by adding a ? to the end of
> parameters we want to be optional. For example, let’s say we want the
> last name parameter from above to be optional:

So, if you want to leave any argument they have to be at the end of the argument list.

The only option you have is to call the function as you did,

```
createVideo(undefined, file)
```

You can make adjustment to your function; if you know that your `file` can never be `undefined` but `uploadedVideo` can, then change the precedence of the parameters.

```
function createVideo(
  file?: File
  uploadedVideo?: Video,
) {
  // if we get uploadedVideo, create VideoForm with video
  // if we get the file, create VideoForm with file
}
```

Now, the first parameter is always file and you need not pass video.

```
createVideo(file)
```

But, a better option is to do a bit of rewrite to your function. Declare the arguments as an object type and you can opt to pass or not pass certain optional params.

```
function createVideo(
  params: 
  {
    uploadedVideo?: Video,
    file?: File
  }
) {

}
```

You can now pass individual parameters, pass both or not pass any,

```
createVideo({ file: file })
createVideo({ uploadedVideo: video })
createVideo({ file: file, uploadedVideo: video })
createVideo({ })
```